# Android ActionBar issue different API < > 21

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

Having issue with ActionBar NullPointerException based on different API. All my activities extend `Activity` .

This is my code:

Gradle

```
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 23    

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Styles (values-v21):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

Activity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
assert actionBar != null;
actionBar.hide();
```

It works fine on **API23** but give `NullPointerException` on lower.

Read other similar question, tried with `ActionBarActivity` (deprecated), `AppCompatActivity`, `SupportActionBar` but I am not able to let it works on different API.

Any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `AppCompatActivity` with `getSupportActionBar()`, which also requires the usage of AppCompat themes on **all** API levels (inlcuding API 21+).

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- use the `AppCompatActivity`
- use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`
- use the same theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for all devices (remove the material theme in v21)

Answer (score 0):

Try extending AppCompatActivity and using getSupportActionBar()